# Does closed questions without an answer count against my accept rate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

If I ask a question that for example is closed as a duplicate before anyone has answered it I won't be able to accept an answer (obviously). Will that question then count against my accept rate, since it has no accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they do not, at least from what I can calculate out my own questions and the accepted percentage there.